# Understanding why my angular controllers aren't updating on model changes

Tags: angularjs, model-binding

I'm new to angular, and I was expecting that whenever I made a change to a model, that change would be reflected in the data in my view through the use of the controller.

I've got a factory which creates my data model

```
app.factory('Calendar', function($http){
  return { months : [//array of month names //],
           calendar : function(){
                      // a bunch of stuff that builds the current month
                return calendar;
                },
            activeDate : function(){
                return this.calendar()[0];
            }
         }
});
```

Then in my controllers I have

```
  app.controller('CalendarCtrl',function($scope,Calendar){
       $scope.calendar = Calendar.calendar();

       $scope.setActiveDay = function(){
           // this is triggered by a click event when the user clicks the day on a calendar
           Calendar.activeDay = this.day;
       }
   });

  app.controller('DayCtrl', function($scope,Calendar){
        $scope.activeDay = Calendar.activeDay();
   });
```

What I was expecting to happen, was that the `setActiveDay` method would change the `Calendar.activeDay` and that the view would automatically be populated with the correct day information.

I output `this.day` from in `setActiveDay`, and I can see that the values are being updated correctly, but the `DayCtrl` isn't picking up the changes.

Can somebody explain to me why this is?? is it because my `Calendar.activeDay` is not a primitive type? If so, how do I get around this? Or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think `$scope.activeDay = Calendar.activeDay();` should be

```
$scope.activeDay = Calendar.activeDay;
```

Now, let's get to your problem. At the beginning, `Calendar.activeDay` and `$scope.activeDay` are referring to the same `this.day`; however, when you do `Calendar.activeDay = this.day` again, `Calendar.activeDay` is changed to point to the new day, but `$scope.activeDay` is still referring to the previous `this.day`, this is the reason why DayCtrl isn't picking up the changes.

It looks like you're using `Calendar` object to communicate between scopes, so one way to solve the problem is to attach `Calendar` object to each scope, and use `Calendar.activeDay` in ngModel. Another way is to use `$scope.$watch` in DayCtrl:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return Calendar.activeDay;
}, function(newDay) {
    $scope.activeDay = newDay;
});
```

Comment: I think I see what you mean jaux. When you say 'attach Calander object to each scope', do you mean that I should have `$scope.calendarObj = Calendar` in each of my controllers? I thought that when I was passing `($scope, Calendar)` into my controllers, that was binding at that point, or am I misunderstanding what you're saying. I'd prefer not to $watch if I don't have to.

Comment: Yes, I mean `$scope.calendarObj = Calendar`. `($scope, Calendar)` means injecting the service into **controller**, so the controller has access to it, but the object won't appear in the scope automatically.

Comment: I ended up having to put both `$scope.calendarObj = Calendar`, as well as `$scope.calendarObj.activeDay = ...` in each of my controllers. This seems a bit verbose, as I thought that with `activeDay` being a copy of the `activeDay` in the `Calendar` model, any updates to the children would be automatically populated.